# Create a composite reference key with novalidate option

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, constraints

I was trying to add a referential constraint on a table using a composite key with a novalidate key as i do have some junk data which i dont want to remove yet.
Below is the example:-

```
alter table SOURCE_SYSTEM add constraint FK_SOURCE_SYSTEM_TENANT foreign key (PLATFORMSET_GUID, TENANT_GUID)
  references EP_TENANT (PLATFORMSET_FK, GUID) ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

but it says

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Comment: `ORA-02270` You must have a primary key in the referencing table. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

The error says it all.

**CAUSE:**

> You tried to reference a table using a unique or primary key, but the
>   columns that you listed did not match the primary key, or a primary
>   key does not exist for this table.

In your case:

> `references EP_TENANT (PLATFORMSET_FK, GUID) ENABLE NOVALIDATE;`

As per the error, there is no **primary key** on the `EP_TENANT` table, you can not create a **foreign key** on the `SOURCE_SYSTEM` table that **references** the EP_TENANT table.

You must first add a primary key to the EP_TENANT table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE EP_TENANT 
 ADD CONSTRAINT PLATFORMSET_PK PRIMARY KEY (PLATFORMSET);
```

Comment: @AthreyTR You're welcome. Please mark it as answered if it has helped you. It would help others too.